# Broken yum update on CentOS 7: gdal

Tags: linux, centos, centos-7, libraries, shared-libraries

When performing:

```
yum update
```

on my CentOS 7 server, I receive this strange error:

```
Error: Package: gdal-1.11.4-12.rhel7.x86_64 (pgdg93)
              Requires: libproj.so.12()(64bit) Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.11.4-12.rhel7.x86_64 (pgdg93)
              Requires: libproj.so.12()(64bit)  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I've never seen this error before.
I've researched a little and GDAL is the [Geospatial Data AbstractionLibrary](http://www.gdal.org).

Apart from the standard CentOS repos, I'm using EPEL, and Postgres 9.3 official repo.

I cannot find `libproj` in [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/download/libproj).

Any ideas on how to solve this please?

Comment: Hey OP, did the accepted answer work for you? Same situation here, but the accepted answer didn't help me jump the gap.

Comment: I ignore the offending `gdal` library.  I hope that in a near future it will be solved.  Postgis and Postgres work ok as before.

Comment: Same issue here.  In my case adding "--exclude=gdal" uncovered another incompatibility between the existing gdal-libs and libarmadillo: "gdal-libs-1.11.4-10 requires libarmadillo.so.4".  I had to use "--exclude=gdal-libs,armadillo" and that got me through the update.  I do not have a clear picture yet if postgis is functioning as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a dependency issue in the Postgres repo, someone filed a bug with exact same message: http://www.postgresql-archive.org/BUG-15037-gdal-libs-1-11-4-12-updates-require-proj-unavailable-version-td6003637.html

You might want to reply to the bugreport to show you're affected too.

Until they fix this you can use:

```
yum update --exclude=gdal
```